# getaddrinfo() returns several identical results

Tags: c, getaddrinfo

In `/etc/hosts` I have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

A test program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

const char* family_to_string(int family)
{
    return family == AF_INET ? "AF_INET"
        : family == AF_INET6 ? "AF_INET6"
        : "<unknown>";
}

const char* socktype_to_string(int socktype)
{
    return socktype == SOCK_STREAM ? "SOCK_STREAM"
        : socktype == SOCK_DGRAM ? "SOCK_DGRAM"
        : "<unknown>";
}

const char* protocol_to_string(int protocol)
{
    return protocol == IPPROTO_TCP ? "IPPROTO_TCP"
        : protocol == IPPROTO_UDP ? "IPPROTO_UDP"
        : "<unknown>";
}

void print_addrinfo(struct addrinfo *ai)
{
    int r;
    char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST], sbuf[NI_MAXSERV];
    r = getnameinfo(ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen, hbuf, sizeof(hbuf), sbuf,
                    sizeof(sbuf), NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
    if (r)
    {
        fputs("getnameinfo\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    const char *family = family_to_string(ai->ai_family);
    const char *socktype = socktype_to_string(ai->ai_socktype);
    const char *protocol = protocol_to_string(ai->ai_protocol);
    const char *family2 = family_to_string(ai->ai_addr->sa_family);
    printf("flags=%i, family=%s, socktype=%s, protocol=%s, family=%s, host=%s, serv=%s\n",
           ai->ai_flags, family, socktype, protocol, family2, hbuf, sbuf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    int r;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *ai;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    // hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    r = getaddrinfo("localhost", "8000", &hints, &result);
    if (r)
    {
        fputs("getaddrinfo\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ai = result;
    while (ai)
    {
        print_addrinfo(ai);
        ai = ai->ai_next;
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I don't set `hints.ai_family`, it's as expected:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors -g -gdwarf-2 -g3 % && ./a.out
flags=0, family=AF_INET6, socktype=SOCK_STREAM, protocol=IPPROTO_TCP, family=AF_INET6, host=::1, serv=8000
flags=0, family=AF_INET, socktype=SOCK_STREAM, protocol=IPPROTO_TCP, family=AF_INET, host=127.0.0.1, serv=8000
```

With `hints.ai_family` it returns two identical `addrinfo` structures:

```
flags=0, family=AF_INET, socktype=SOCK_STREAM, protocol=IPPROTO_TCP, family=AF_INET, host=127.0.0.1, serv=8000
flags=0, family=AF_INET, socktype=SOCK_STREAM, protocol=IPPROTO_TCP, family=AF_INET, host=127.0.0.1, serv=8000
```

Can you explain what's going on? I thought `hints` acts as a filter. That is, only one result is to be returned in this case.

**UPD** `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
# Begin /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd: compat mymachines systemd
group: compat mymachines systemd
shadow: compat

publickey: files

hosts: files mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
networks: files

protocols: files
services: files
ethers: files
rpc: files

netgroup: files

# End /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
search Dlink
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

`192.168.0.1` is my router. My IP address is `192.168.0.39`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this here. What OS and resolver library are you seeing this with? Side note: To be portable, this needs an `#include <netinet/in.h>` for `IPPROTO_*`.

Comment: Arch Linux, `glibc-2.26`.

Comment: And `resolv.conf` points directly to the upstream resolver or do you run a stub-resolver, e.g. `systemd-resolved` or similar?

Comment: `systemd-resolved` service is not started/enabled. Added info to the question. Not sure what's stub resolver. So if I have one, it was installed by some other software. Which is unlikely.

Comment: A stub resolver is a local DNS server that only forwards DNS queries to other servers. systemd-resolved is one of those. You don't have one enabled, your system is directly querying your router (as indicated by your `resolv.conf`). Given the query, there shouldn't be any DNS traffic involved at all, since `localhost` is resolvable from `/etc/hosts`. Also: I'm out of guesses.

Comment: @dhke I think I've figured out, what's going on: https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2018-01/msg00004.html And now it's not clear why you can't reproduce it. Have you run the test program? With `hints.ai_family = AF_INET` it returns only one result? What's your OS and `glibc` version? But well, the behavior was introduced around 2016. Also, do you have `multi on` in `/etc/host.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see:

[sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c:2206](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c;h=2c4b6d6793a4c3a96eb1e545570ac28867681751;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l2206)

```
int
getaddrinfo (const char *name, const char *service,
             const struct addrinfo *hints, struct addrinfo **pai)
```

[sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c:2304](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c;h=2c4b6d6793a4c3a96eb1e545570ac28867681751;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l2304)

```
last_i = gaih_inet (name, pservice, hints, end, &naddrs, &tmpbuf);
```

[sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c:342](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c;h=2c4b6d6793a4c3a96eb1e545570ac28867681751;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l342)

```
static int
gaih_inet (const char *name, const struct gaih_service *service,
           const struct addrinfo *req, struct addrinfo **pai,
           unsigned int *naddrs, struct scratch_buffer *tmpbuf)
```

[sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c:595](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c;h=2c4b6d6793a4c3a96eb1e545570ac28867681751;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l595)

```
rc = __gethostbyname2_r (name, AF_INET, &th,
                         tmpbuf->data, tmpbuf->length,
                         &h, &h_errno);
```

[nss/getXXbyYY_r.c:189](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/getXXbyYY_r.c;h=bce80e05dd2d176467809faf353828f50cf76eaf;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l189)

```
int
INTERNAL (REENTRANT_NAME) (ADD_PARAMS, LOOKUP_TYPE *resbuf, char *buffer,
                           size_t buflen, LOOKUP_TYPE **result H_ERRNO_PARM
                           EXTRA_PARAMS)
```

[nss/getXXbyYY_r.c:316](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/getXXbyYY_r.c;h=bce80e05dd2d176467809faf353828f50cf76eaf;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l316)

```
status = DL_CALL_FCT (fct.l, (ADD_VARIABLES, resbuf, buffer, buflen,
                              &errno H_ERRNO_VAR EXTRA_VARIABLES));
```

[nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c:385](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c;h=6f7cc4d94ba69ab58d684f63cc685f6fa5c6ad4a;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l385)

```
enum nss_status
_nss_files_gethostbyname2_r (const char *name, int af, struct hostent *result,
                             char *buffer, size_t buflen, int *errnop,
                             int *herrnop)
```

[nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c:389](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c;h=6f7cc4d94ba69ab58d684f63cc685f6fa5c6ad4a;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l389)

```
return _nss_files_gethostbyname3_r (name, af, result, buffer, buflen,
                                    errnop, herrnop, NULL, NULL);
```

[nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c:334](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c;h=6f7cc4d94ba69ab58d684f63cc685f6fa5c6ad4a;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l334)

```
enum nss_status
_nss_files_gethostbyname3_r (const char *name, int af, struct hostent *result,
                             char *buffer, size_t buflen, int *errnop,
                             int *herrnop, int32_t *ttlp, char **canonp)
```

Here we get first match, and—if `multi` is `on` in `/etc/host.conf`—the rest of them:

[nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c:352](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c;h=6f7cc4d94ba69ab58d684f63cc685f6fa5c6ad4a;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l352)

```
while ((status = internal_getent (stream, result, buffer, buflen, errnop,
                                  herrnop, af, flags))
       == NSS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
  {
    LOOKUP_NAME_CASE (h_name, h_aliases)
  }

if (status == NSS_STATUS_SUCCESS
    && _res_hconf.flags & HCONF_FLAG_MULTI)
  status = gethostbyname3_multi
    (stream, name, af, result, buffer, buflen, errnop, herrnop, flags);
```

[nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c:127](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c;h=6f7cc4d94ba69ab58d684f63cc685f6fa5c6ad4a;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l127)

```
static enum nss_status
gethostbyname3_multi (FILE * stream, const char *name, int af,
                      struct hostent *result, char *buffer, size_t buflen,
                      int *errnop, int *herrnop, int flags)
```

[nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c:162](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c;h=6f7cc4d94ba69ab58d684f63cc685f6fa5c6ad4a;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l162)

```
status = internal_getent (stream, &tmp_result_buf, tmp_buffer.data,
                          tmp_buffer.length, errnop, herrnop, af,
                          flags);
```

[nss/nss_files/files-XXX.c:178](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-XXX.c;h=265331ef21cd60ed301ab49eac4d6681d74bb388;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l178)

```
static enum nss_status
internal_getent (FILE *stream, struct STRUCTURE *result,
                 char *buffer, size_t buflen, int *errnop H_ERRNO_PROTO
                 EXTRA_ARGS_DECL)
```

[nss/nss_files/files-XXX.c:222](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-XXX.c;h=265331ef21cd60ed301ab49eac4d6681d74bb388;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l222)

```
|| ! (parse_result = parse_line (p, result, data, buflen, errnop
                                 EXTRA_ARGS)));
```

Here we parse "::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost" line. We try
to run `inet_pton` over `::1`. That fails, since `af == AF_INET`. Then we
notice that `::1` is IPv6 loopback address, so we return IPv4 loopback
address:

[nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c:51](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c;h=6f7cc4d94ba69ab58d684f63cc685f6fa5c6ad4a;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l51)

```
LINE_PARSER
```

[nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c:59](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c;h=6f7cc4d94ba69ab58d684f63cc685f6fa5c6ad4a;hb=633e2f7f3d88df6427aa3a7a984d3a6b796d9611#l59)

```
if (inet_pton (af == AF_UNSPEC ? AF_INET : af, addr, entdata->host_addr)
    > 0)
  af = af == AF_UNSPEC ? AF_INET : af;
else
  {
    if (...)
      ...
    else if (af == AF_INET
             && inet_pton (AF_INET6, addr, entdata->host_addr) > 0)
      {
        if (...)
          ...
        else if (IN6_IS_ADDR_LOOPBACK (entdata->host_addr))
          {
            in_addr_t localhost = htonl (INADDR_LOOPBACK);
            memcpy (entdata->host_addr, &localhost, sizeof (localhost));
          }
```

Maybe somebody on the [mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2018-01/msg00004.html) will reply, and we'll learn even more.